# Creating Document Libraries through Flow with a single API call

Tags: json, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

My company currently have client SharePoint sites hosted on our O365 tenant, and previously whenever a new client was bought on board we'd create a SharePoint site for them using the GUI or Powershell, but in the interest of making things a little easier in the long run I'm now in the process of trying to automate site creation for any new clients that join us - Historically, all sites have been designed the same with more or less the same structure, the only difference being the files themselves. I've managed to automate the bulk of the SharePoint site creation through flow (Creating the site, Hub site linkage, ownership of site, group membership, external access, etc.) but I'm having trouble with creating the document libraries on newly created sites. There are 8 libraries overall, and whilst I have actually worked out how to create them each individually using the 'Send a HTTP request to SharePoint" action (I'm quite new to Flow and all this!), I'd like to try and use MS Graph and JSON batching instead, so I can create all 8 libraries in a single API call.

I've tested my JSON on the MS Graph Explorer, which works and and creates the libraries on a specified client site as expected, but when I try and do it through Flow, I get the below error and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5EGH.png)

The error message singles out the Headers, but I'm not sure what the issue is?
See below the HTTP action in the Flow:

[HTTP Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAb8N.png)

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "method": "POST",
        "uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "authorization": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['token_type']} @{body('Parse_JSON')?['access_token']}"
        },
        "body": {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/BSS:/lists",
                    "body": {
                        "displayName": "Management",
                        "list": {
                            "template": "documentLibrary"
                        }
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/BSS:/lists",
                    "body": {
                        "displayName": "Employees",
                        "list": {
                            "template": "documentLibrary"
                        }
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/BSS:/lists",
                    "body": {
                        "displayName": "Work Activities",
                        "list": {
                            "template": "documentLibrary"
                        }
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/BSS:/lists",
                    "body": {
                        "displayName": "Work Equipment",
                        "list": {
                            "template": "documentLibrary"
                        }
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/BSS:/lists",
                    "body": {
                        "displayName": "Substances",
                        "list": {
                            "template": "documentLibrary"
                        }
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/BSS:/lists",
                    "body": {
                        "displayName": "Workplaces",
                        "list": {
                            "template": "documentLibrary"
                        }
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "7",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/BSS:/lists",
                    "body": {
                        "displayName": "HR",
                        "list": {
                            "template": "documentLibrary"
                        }
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "8",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/BSS:/lists",
                    "body": {
                        "displayName": "Quality",
                        "list": {
                            "template": "documentLibrary"
                        }
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Would anyone be able to offer any insight?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Weird, works for me"

Header parameters are correct (case insensitive) as well as request's body.
MS Flow sometimes behave totally unexplainably.

Please try again creating temporary flow with OAuth2 token HTTP request and Graph API HTTP request only.

For token JSON parsing purposes I used this schema:

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "token_type": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "expires_in": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "ext_expires_in": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "access_token": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That's actually how my token schema appears. Anyway I've just created a new Flow with just the token request and the API HTTP request, and it's worked?!?

I can't see what the problem was since it's all written the exact same way as it was in the original flow, so I'm just going to have to go with what you said and that it's just Flow behaving strangely.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is also a great Microsoft Flow tutorial you can take  a look at.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/flow

Comment: @Guero unfortunately no matter how great and useful MS Flow actually is, I have to say that it's still a buggy and sometimes the only explanation is 'there is no explanation'.
Coming back to your question - I think that using `Apply to each` action + eg. SharePoint list might be better (in terms of transparency) resolution than hardcoding JSON with separate requests and calling `$batch` endpoint of MS Graph API